# Problem with Mathematica's KarhunenLoeveExpansion's output

Tags: statistics, wolfram-mathematica, eigenvalue, coordinate-transformation, eigenvector

I have a matrix called realizationMat, it contains 101 measurements of 90 realizations of a stochastic process. I will post instead an abridged 11*5 smaller example

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]]}     
{xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[0, 1, .1], Range[0, 1, .1]];
kernel = Exp[(-1)*Abs[xx - yy]]; 
{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[kernel];
realizationNumber = 5;
longitudeOfEigA = Length[evec];
realizationNumber = 5;
evecRand = 0*ConstantArray[1, {longitudeOfEigA}];
realizationMat = 0*ConstantArray[1, {realizationNumber}];
For[i = 0, i < realizationNumber + 1, i++,
For[j = 0, j < longitudeOfEigA, j++;
evecRand[[j]] = 
eval[[j]]^0.5*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]*
evec[[j]]; (*Print[i];*)realization = Total[evecRand, {1}]; 
realizationMat[[i]] = realization]];
VA1 = realizationMat[[1]];
VA2 = realizationMat[[2]];
VA3 = realizationMat[[3]];
VA4 = realizationMat[[4]];
VA5 = realizationMat[[5]];
KLVariablesB = KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[{VA1, VA2, VA3, VA4, VA5}];
```

In the documentation is written:  **rows of the transformation matrix m are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix formed from the arrays ai.** Also,  **The transformed arrays bi are uncorrelated, are given in order of decreasing variance, and have the same total variance as ai.**

However, if I write `ListPlot[{KLVariablesB[[2, 1]]}, Joined -> True]`, it doesn't look like an eigenvector at all, see figure 1

[image: Figure 1, fist row of m]. Also, if I instead plot `ListPlot[{KLVariablesB[[1, 1]]}, Joined -> True]`, it looks way more as an eigenvector, see figure 2[image: Figure 2], yet these aren't the eigenvectors of the original covariance matrix.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Best regards.

I am also attaching an image of the original eigenvectors of the kernel

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code as given

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]]}     
{xx, yy} = meshgrid[Range[0, 1, .1], Range[0, 1, .1]];
kernel = Exp[(-1)*Abs[xx - yy]]; 
{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[kernel];
realizationNumber = 5;
longitudeOfEigA = Length[evec];
realizationNumber = 5;
evecRand = 0*ConstantArray[1, {longitudeOfEigA}];
realizationMat = 0*ConstantArray[1, {realizationNumber}];
For[i = 0, i < realizationNumber + 1, i++,
For[j = 0, j < longitudeOfEigA, j++;
evecRand[[j]] = 
eval[[j]]^0.5*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]*
evec[[j]]; (*Print[i];*)realization = Total[evecRand, {1}]; 
realizationMat[[i]] = realization]];
VA1 = realizationMat[[1]];
VA2 = realizationMat[[2]];
VA3 = realizationMat[[3]];
VA4 = realizationMat[[4]];
VA5 = realizationMat[[5]];
KLVariablesB = KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[{VA1, VA2, VA3, VA4, VA5}];

lp = ListLinePlot[{KLVariablesB[[2, 1]]}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic];

Manipulate[Show[Plot[a Sin[b + c x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}], lp,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-6, 6}}],
 {{a, 6}, 0.5, 8}, {{b, 0.21}, 0, 4}, {{c, 3.1}, 1, 10}]
```

It appears you don't have enough resolution.  A sine wave can be matched up to the output.

[image]

Note, there is a Stack Exchange site dedicated to Mathematica here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/